# How to initialize class in class Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I learning to Ruby and I stuck, so I have a question.
How to initialize the class in another class, and is this possible?
I try to write a simple game "Dog's Runs".
Here are the classes:

Class DOG showing information about dogs.

```rb
class DOG
  def initialize(breed,name,weight=0,height=0,speed=0)
    @the_weight = weight
    @the_height = height
    @the_breed = breed.capitalize
    @the_name = name.capitalize
    @the_speed = speed
  end

  def to_s
    "                    DOG INFORMATION
                  His name is: #{@the_name}
                  His breed is: #{@the_breed}
                  His weight is: #{@the_weight} cm
                  His height is: #{@the_height} kg
              His average speed is: #{@the_speed} km/h
        "
  end
end
```

class GAME

```rb
class GAME
    def initialize_game
       luckS = rand(0..10)
       luckR = rand(0..10)
       luckW = rand(0..10)
        if choose_dog == "Steve\n" or choose_dog == "steve\n" or choose_dog == "whippet\n" or choose_dog == "Whippet\n"
            if choose_rate == 3.33
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 3.33!"
                puts "The game starts!"
                if luckS > luckR and luckS > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 6.66
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 6.66!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckS > luckR and luckS > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 10.00
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 10.00!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckS > luckR and luckS > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
        end
        if choose_dog == "Richard\n" or choose_dog == "richard\n" or choose_dog == "greyhound\n" or choose_dog == "Greyhound\n"
            puts "Great pick!"
            puts "Choose rate!"
            puts "First rate is 3.33 , please write in 3.33 if you want to pick that rate"
            puts "Second rate is 3.33 , please write in 6.66 if you want to pick that rate"
            puts "Third rate is 3.33 , please write in 10.00 if you want to pick that rate"
            if choose_rate == 3.33
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 3.33!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckR > luckS and luckR > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 6.66
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 6.66!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckR > luckS and luckR > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 10.00
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 10.00!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckR > luckS and luckR > luckW
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
        end
        if choose_dog == "Whilley\n" or choose_dog == "whilley\n" or choose_dog == "saluki\n" or choose_dog == "Saluki\n"
            puts "Great pick!"
            puts "Choose rate!"
            puts "First rate is 3.33 , please write in 3.33 if you want to pick that rate"
            puts "Second rate is 3.33 , please write in 6.66 if you want to pick that rate"
            puts "Third rate is 3.33 , please write in 10.00 if you want to pick that rate"
            if choose_rate == 3.33
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 3.33!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckW > luckS and luckW > luckR
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 6.66
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 6.66!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckW > luckS and luckW > luckR
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
            if choose_rate == 10.00
                puts "You choosed , your rate is 10.00!"
                puts "The game is starts!"
                if luckW > luckS and luckW > luckR
                    puts "You win!"
                    puts "Take your cash."
                    money = money + (money*choose_rate)
                else
                    puts "You lose"
                    money = money - (money*choose_rate)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And other code that must run GAME class:

```rb
puts "Hello to our \"Dog's Runs!\""
        money = 1000
        puts "Here's information about our dogs"
        dogs=[DOG.new("whippet","Steve",15,48,50),DOG.new("greyhound","Richard",34,73,70),DOG.new("saluki","Whilley",20,61,60)]
        puts dogs
        puts "Please , write in dog's name or breed:"
        choose_dog = gets.to_s
        puts "Great pick!"
        puts "Choose rate!"
        puts "First rate is 3.33 , please write in 3.33 if you want to pick that rate"
        puts "Second rate is 3.33 , please write in 6.66 if you want to pick that rate"
        puts "Third rate is 3.33 , please write in 10.00 if you want to pick that rate"
        choose_rate = gets.to_f
        GAME.new.initialize_game
```

I changed most of code , but i just can't initialize that GAME class , i wrote GAME.new.initialize_game with class_name and method, but that still won't work.

Comment: You want the `GAME` class to be initialized in `CHOOSE` class, right?

Comment: Yes , so if i initialize class GAME in class CHOOSE i will be able to make a cycle with a bet game :)

Comment: `GAME.new.initialize_game` this should be enough.

Comment: I put it, and I see only:

dogsruns.rb(main):192:1>    enddogsruns.rb(main):192:1> 
=> :initialize_game
dogsruns.rb(main):192:0>

idk how to help that :/

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question is that I can't initialize class GAME in class CHOOSE.
And idk is that possible.

Comment: But you initialized `Dog.new` in your `Choose`. What's the difference between `Game` and `Dog`? Use [CamelCase](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes) for classes

Comment: @I.Kyskyn In the game class, you expect 2 inputs from user. With this given inputs you are doing some comparisons. When you run this method on ruby console then what is the output? And does this method force you to give inputs?

Comment: Oh, understood, thanks guys, my bad :)
I think this method forces me to give inputs, I must input rate and a breed/name of the dog.

Comment: Ruby has strong conventions when it comes to names. Classes follow `ClassName` format, constants `CONSTANT_NAME`. All-caps classes are generally frowned upon with exceptions made for acronyms like `HTTP` or `URI`. Another thing to consider is to avoid variable of the form `dog1`, `dog2` and so on and instead have an array `dogs = [ ]` that you can put things into and, more importantly, *iterate over*. This code is three times as long as it needs to be due to duplication.

Comment: So if I'll create array dogs, I should do something like that?:
dogs = ["#{@breed}","#{@name}","#{@weight}","#{@height}",]
But I don't understand how to use this :/
And I deleted classes MONEY and CHOOSE, and put them outta classes:
choose_dog = gets.to_s
choose_rate = gets
money = 1000
But the program still won't work and I'm still tryin' to initialize method from class GAME :/
Sry for my stupid brain thought

Comment: Why do you persist in using the wrong syntax?

Comment: Remember `"#{x}"` and `x` are almost always the same, so instead of `"#{@breed}"` do just `@breed`. It removes considerable clutter from your code.

Comment: When creating an array of objects: `dogs = [ Dog.new(...), Dog.new(...), ...]` where each `new` call has the appropriate arguments. Then you can refer to `dog[0]` and such, or `dogs.each do |dog|`. The real strength of Ruby comes from [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html) and to use that you need to use some kind of container like an array or hash.

Comment: *"I wrote `GAME.new.initialize_game` with class_name and method, but that still won't work."* - What's the error you encounter? Or what is different than expected? (Provide the actual output and the expected output in the question.)

Comment: 1. Changed that duplicated dogs to an array, ty @tadman
2. I want to initialize class GAME. Zeitnot wrote: GAME.new.initialize_game this should be enough." , I wrote this in code but i see only "undefined local variable or method choose_dog for #<GAME:0x0000561774cbdb58>"
I can't understand what's bad with this choose_dog, I think I wrote this variable right.
Expected output is the class GAME will be initialized, so bet-game will start.
(P.S I live in Russia, so sorry for my English and understanding all these messages:////)

Comment: Those variables are undefined because you didn't pass them in. They're "out of scope" in Ruby terms.

Comment: Ty guys, the game is starting now. Sorry for all that troubles.

Comment: "but that still won't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure to actually supply a [mcve]. For example, I am pretty sure that you do not require 163 lines to demonstrate your problem. Are you sure that there is not a single line that you could remove to make this easier to read and easier to debug? Personally, I am willing to bet that you could replicate your problem in less than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code, and there's a clear error message. Maybe you're running the code in some way that's not showing you the error message?

```
Great pick!
Choose rate!
First rate is 3.33 , please write in 3.33 if you want to pick that rate
Second rate is 3.33 , please write in 6.66 if you want to pick that rate
Third rate is 3.33 , please write in 10.00 if you want to pick that rate
6.66
/Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:26:in `initialize_game': undefined local variable or method `choose_dog' for #<GAME:0x00007f9a7208a5c0> (NameError)
    from /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:171:in `<main>'
```

`Game#initialize_game` is referencing `choose_dog` and `choose_rate` and `money`. While those are variables in the main program, they're not available anywhere else. This lets you isolate parts of the program from each other. If you want to use them in a method they need to be passed in.

```
# In GAME
def initialize_game(choose_dog, choose_rate, money)

# When calling it.
GAME.new.initialize_game(choose_dog, choose_rate, money)
```

Comment: I added choosing into GAME class to avoid error.
The game is starting, but with another error lol:

Please, write in dog's name or breed:
Steve
Great pick!
Choose rate!
3.33
You choosed , your rate is 3.33!
The game starts!
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        2: from dogsruns2.rb:165
        1: from dogsruns2.rb:42:in `initialize_game'
NoMethodError (undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass)
I just want to make:
Money = money +(money*choose_rate)
Now I don't understand again, and again sorry for my stupid brain thoughts.

Comment: @I.Kyskyn You're still missing one of `money` or `choose_rate`.

Comment: I changed the code, the game is working properly now.
Thanks to you all guys for help.
<3

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here at what you're asking, but looking at your code and the comments, you're trying to get the dogs you created (in your last snippet) into the "game" you created.

There's a number of slick ways you can do so via following different design patterns, but I'd stick with something more straightforward while you're learning: tell the Game class that the dog or dog(s) that exist:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :dogs

  def initialize(*dogs)
    @dogs = dogs
  end

  def play
    puts "For tonights race we have:"
    dogs.each do |dog|
      puts dog.name
    end
  end
end

d1 = Dog.new('Joe')
d2 = Dog.new('Sally')
d3 = Dog.new('Steve')

game = Game.new(d1, d2, d3)

game.play
```

You could optionally create the dogs automatically when you create the game:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :dogs

  def initialize
    load_dogs
  end

  def play
    puts "For tonights race we have:"
    dogs.each do |dog|
      puts dog.name
    end
  end

  private

  def load_dogs
    @dogs = []
    @dogs << Dog.new('Joe')
    @dogs << Dog.new('Sally')
    @dogs << Dog.new('Steve')
  end
end

game = Game.new

game.play
```

You can then integrate your choice into the game code:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :dogs

  def initialize
    load_dogs
  end

  def play
    puts "For tonights race we have:"
    dogs.each do |dog|
      puts dog.name
    end

    puts

    choose_your_dog
  end

  private

  def choose_your_dog
    puts "Which dog do you want"
    @choice = gets.to_s.strip
    puts "You choose #{@choice}; great choice!"
  end

  def load_dogs
    @dogs = []
    @dogs << Dog.new('Joe')
    @dogs << Dog.new('Sally')
    @dogs << Dog.new('Steve')
  end
end

game = Game.new

game.play
```

Comment: This code is more simple and productive than mine, so many methods that my eyes scatter, I gonna try to make mine code simpler on your example , thanks so much :)